# AWS CDK autoscalingGroup schedule automatically adapts to summer and winter times?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, aws-cdk, aws-auto-scaling

When adding a schedule to an autoscaling group via CDK, I can select the **timezone**:

```
declare autoscalingGroup: IAutoscalingGroup;

autoscalingGroup.scaleOnSchedule(
  "LogicalId",
  {
    minCapacity: 150,
    maxCapacity: 150,
    schedule: Schedule.expression("0 18 * * *"),
    timeZone: "Europe/Berlin"
  }
 );
```

What does the code above **mean**? Will I automatically scale down to 150 instances at 16.00 UTC during summer, but at 17.00 UTC during winter?

---

CDK reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_autoscaling.BasicScheduledActionProps.html

Cloudformation reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-as-scheduledaction.html#cfn-as-scheduledaction-timezone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes -- it means exactly that. UTC is constant and is unaffected by daylight savings unlike CEST.

So because you've used a CEST timezone, your scaling will happen at different UTC times in summer and winter as you've correctly stated.

> By default, the recurring schedules that you set are in Coordinated
> Universal Time (UTC). You can change the time zone to correspond to
> your local time zone or a time zone for another part of your network.
> When you specify a time zone that observes Daylight Saving Time (DST),
> the action automatically adjusts for DST. -- [Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/ec2-auto-scaling-scheduled-scaling.html)